# php to get third level html list (li) elements

Tags: php, regression

I have an Html List like this

```
    $html = 
'<ul>
    <li>prices are rounded to 4 decimasls (this is Opencart default). Due to this there might be some loss of accuracy when changing back and forth from one currency to another.</li>
    <li>automatic backup before the convertion saves only the prices and store settings. It is [b]not saving whole database backup[/b]. You should do full backup before installation yourself as a best practice.</li>
    <li>
    The prices are recalculated for the extensions listed below. If you need to change prices in other extensions, you must do it manually:
            <ul>
                <li>Shipping extensions that are affected:
                    <ul>
                        <li>Flat Rate,</li>
                        <li>Per Item,</li>
                        <li>Free shipping</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Payment modules that are affected:
                    <ul>
                        <li>COD,</li>
                        <li>Authorize Net,</li>
                        <li>Bank Transffer,</li>
                        <li>Liqpay</li>
                        <li>Moneybookers</li>
                        <li>Nochex</li>
                        <li>Paymate</li>
                        <li>Worldpay</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Totals extensions that are affected<ul>
                <li>Handling Total</li>
                <li>Low order Fee Total</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>';
```

I want to replace third level  li with --- for intend rather than using li like

```
<li>
---Flat Rate,
---Per Item,
---Free Shipping
</li>
```

How can i achieve this using php dom library.

or removing all

and simply intending will also to

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it show no own effort to solve the problem whatsoever.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve could be done with css.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS:

```
<style>
li li li:before {
    content:"---";
    } 
</style>
```

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "li li li" ).prepend('---');
});
```

With PHP:
Manipluating the DOM is not as easy in PHP as it is with Javascript and CSS. You can either build a custom function that iterates through your element and reformats it or look for an existing DOM parser such as http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net.

My advise - stick with jQuery or CSS to keep your blood pressure down.

Hope this helps!